# Assign identifier to every inheriting class

Tags: python, metaprogramming

Ok, so the thing is let's say we have this piece of code:

```
class Master(object):
    id = SomePythonMagic()


class Slave1(master):
    pass

class Slave2(master):
    pass

class Slave3(master):
    pass



slave1 = Slave1()
print slave1.id
>> 1
slave2 = Slave2()
print slave2.id
>> 2
slave3 = Slave3()
print slave3.id
>> 3
slave4 = Slave1()
print slave4.id
>> 1
```

The thing is I want every class that inherits the masterclass to get it's own id, awesome would be if it could be a plain counter, but any id is ok.
I want the ID's to be embedded into the meta class so even if I call Slave1.id I would still get the number 1, as with every instance of the class as well.

Does anyone have any idea or solution to this issue?

Comment: May I ask *why* do you want to do this? Do you have dynamic generation of classes that you need to persist, or something like that?

Comment: Why don't just randomize an id each time the subclass' `__init__` gets called?

Comment: @goncalopp Let's just say I want to place a dynamic identifier on all classes that inherit from a certain abstract class, I could hardcode the values into all of those forms, but I just wanted a more pythonic solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case for [meta class](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation). Meta classes are the classes which customize the construction of other classes.

```
# Define the metaclass
class metacls(type):
    counter = 0
    def __new__(meta_class, name, bases, attributes):
        attributes['id'] = metacls.counter
        metacls.counter += 1
        return type.__new__(meta_class, name, bases, attributes)

# Set the metaclass    
class Master(object): __metaclass__ = metacls

class Slave1(Master): pass
class Slave2(Master): pass
class Slave3(Master): pass

print Slave1.id, Slave1().id
# 1 1
print Slave2.id, Slave2().id
# 2 2
print Slave3.id, Slave3().id
# 3 3
```

Comment: YES YES YES !!! You sir won the game! I was trying to do this by extending the type and adding the metaclass, but I was so fed up with the issue, I completely forgot I just had to add the ID into the attribute dict, THANK YOU That's the solution I was aiming for !!! Correct 100%

Comment: @BojanJovanovic Glad to have been of help :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
class ClassIncrementor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = 0
    def __call__(self, cls):
        self.id += 1
        cls.id = self.id
        return cls
taskIncrementor = ClassIncrementor()


@taskIncrementor
class Slave1(object):
    pass

@taskIncrementor
class Slave2(object):
    pass

@taskIncrementor
class Slave3(object):
    pass
```

Result:

```
(1, <__main__.Slave2 object at 0x021C1DF0>)
(0, <__main__.Slave1 object at 0x021CA130>)
(2, <__main__.Slave3 object at 0x021CA290>)
(2, <__main__.Slave3 object at 0x021CA290>)
(2, <__main__.Slave3 object at 0x021CA290>)
```

This is a solution I was after, if anyone has a better idea how to solve this, please by all means :)

Answer (score 0):

You said incrementing is optional, yes?

If you can use a pseudo-random way to id the objects, you might be able to get away with just calling `id(self)` during the `__init__` call.

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.uid = id(self)
... 
>>> Stick = A()
>>> Stick.uid
4385894928
>>> Jupiter = A()
>>> Jupiter.uid
4385894672
```

Comment: no, the thing is I need a unique integer as ID per object not their instance. so STick and Jupiter need to have the same ID, preferabbly a small int that increments on each inheritance of the masterclass

Comment: I couldn't unfortunately create anything that does that in the base class so I just added a decorator that increaments their number by one... it's just like hardcoding the id but, meh a bit less error prone I wreckin